# Java Scanner.nextInt() throws NoSuchElementException for seemingly no reason

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        DBConnectionPool.ConnectionPool();
        int scelta = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);            
        for(;;) {


            System.out.println("Selezionare il tipo di operazione da eseguire:");
            System.out.println("1: Inserimento");
            System.out.println("2: Modifica");
            System.out.println("3: Cancellazione");
            System.out.println("4: Altre");
            System.out.println("5: Liste");
            System.out.println("98: TEST");
            System.out.println("99: Esci");

            scelta = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            switch (scelta) {
            case 1: opInserimento(sc);
            break;
            case 2: opModifica(sc);
            break;
            case 3: opCancella(sc);
            break;
            case 4: altreOp(sc);
            break;
            case 5: liste(sc);
            break;
            case 98: testSuite.testStart();
            case 99:
                System.out.println("Uscita");
                sc.close();
                return;
            }
                        }

        }
```

This cycle works for the first time, but after the selected method returns, once it gets to the nextInt() it throws NoSuchElementException. The inside of one of those methods (they're all the same pretty much)

```
static private void opInserimento(Scanner sc) {

int selezione = 0;

System.out.println("Selezionare l'operazione: ");
System.out.println("1: Inserisci allievo");
System.out.println("2: Inserisci corso");
System.out.println("3: Inserisci esame");
System.out.println("4: Inserisci gara");
System.out.println("5: Inserisci istruttore");
System.out.println("6: Inserisci lezione");
System.out.println("7: Inserisci sede");
System.out.println("8: Inserisci numero di telefono di un allievo");
System.out.println("9: Inserisci numero di telefono di un'istruttore");
System.out.println("99: Indietro");

selezione = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

switch(selezione) {
case 1: QueryInserimento.inserireAllievo();
break;
case 2: QueryInserimento.inserireCorso();
break;
case 3: QueryInserimento.inserireEsame();
break;
case 4: QueryInserimento.inserireGara();
break;
case 5: QueryInserimento.inserireIstruttore();
break;
case 6: QueryInserimento.inserireLezione();
break;
case 7: QueryInserimento.inserireSede();
break;
case 8: QueryUtenti.aggiungiTelefonoAllievo();
break;
case 9: QueryUtenti.aggiungiTelefonoIstruttore();
break;
case 99: return;
 }
}
```

It's a sub-menu basically. If I skip the switch block the cycle works fine, so I'm assuming it must be a problem that happens in the sub-menu. Any ideas?

Comment: What was the action you took, on the sub-menu, that made the error occur?

Comment: Your code is perfectly working. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Did you accidentally hit return twice when making the first entry? You could check if the user entered an Integer and if not let him try again.